Extension of the definition of eigenvalue
Suppose we have a field $K$ and a field extension $L/K$. We also have a vector space $V$ over $L$, which, when we restrict the base field, gives us a vector space over $K$. We will call the vector space over $K$ to be $V_K$. We further define a linear transformation $T:V_K\to V_K$. Now we can extend the definition of eigenvalue: $\alpha\in L$ is an eigenvalue if there exists some $v\in V_K$ such that $T(v)=\alpha v$ where $\alpha v$ is scalar multiplication in $V$. Note $V_K=V$ as sets so this makes sense.
I suspect there should be some reason eigenvalue is not defined like this, so I'm wondering if the usual properties of eigenvalue holds (as in the usual definition eigenvalue is strictly in the base field). I'll list a few below:
(1) $\alpha\in L$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ if and only if $x-\alpha$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $T$.
(2) If the characteristic polynomial splits in $L$, then the trace of $T$ is the sum of all roots, counting multiplicity. And its product would be the determinant.

Not any special insight just a guess on my part: That definition does seem rather abstract--and intimidating--for a college undergraduate just getting introduced to matrices
